# UIImage won't take anything but the array

Tags: swift, image, imageview

I can't get the `UIImage` to take anything except the array. I have tried several different options including creating a var or putting the image name in there and I can't seem to get it to take.

```
@IBAction func displayPressed(_ sender: Any) { 
    externalPicture.image = UIImage (named: externalArray [1])
    seatingSetup.image = UIImage (named: seatingArray ["\(forPicture())" + "seating"])
}

func forPicture() -> String {
    var aircraftFullName = ""
    let manuf = aircraftType.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let model = aircraftType.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
    if manuf < aircraft.count {
        aircraftFullName = aircraft[manuf]
        if let aircraftModels =  models[aircraftFullName] {
            if model < aircraftModels.count {
                aircraftFullName = aircraftFullName  + " " + aircraftModels[model]
            }
        }
    }
    selectedAircraft.text = aircraftFullName

    if aircraftFullName != "0" {}
    return "\(aircraftFullName)"
}

let aircraft = ["Airbus", "Boeing", "Bombardier", "Embraer"]
var models = [ "Airbus": ["A300", "A320", "A330", "A340", "A350", "A380"], "Boeing": ["B737", "B747", "B757", "767", "777", "787"], "Bombardier": ["CRJ200", "CRJ700/900"], "Embraer": ["ERJ145", "ERJ170", "ERJ190"] ]

var externalArray = ["320outside", "747outside"]
var seatingArray = ["AirbusA320seating", "BoeingB747seating"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to convert this

```
aircraftFullName = aircraftFullName  + " " + aircraftModels[model]
```

to

```
aircraftFullName = aircraftFullName + aircraftModels[model]
```

**Edit** :  according to your `forPicture()` method the image should be like this **Airbus A320seating** but for **AirbusA320seating** you need to remove the mentioned space like above

```
seatingSetup.image = UIImage (named:"\(forPicture())" + "seating")
```

//

if you want to keep space to show in the textfield you can create other var and return it like this

```
func forPicture() -> String {
    var aircraftFullName = ""
    var aircraftFullNameNoSpace = ""
    let manuf = aircraftType.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let model = aircraftType.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
    if manuf < aircraft.count {
        aircraftFullName = aircraft[manuf]
        if let aircraftModels =  models[aircraftFullName] {
            if model < aircraftModels.count {
                aircraftFullName = aircraftFullName  + " " + aircraftModels[model]
                aircraftFullNameNoSpace = aircraftFullName + aircraftModels[model]
            }
        }
    }
    selectedAircraft.text = aircraftFullName

    if aircraftFullName != "0" {}
    return aircraftFullNameNoSpace 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem and I put that in there to get a space between the manufacturer and type aircraft for another part of the code.  I appreciate the input though!

Comment: yes , but the image name **Airbus A320seating** differs from **AirbusA320seating**

Comment: also the array **seatingArray** can't have a string index in **seatingArray ["\\(forPicture())" + "seating"]**

Comment: yes thats the issue I am having, so how else could I word it to allow me to pull the image for the associated plane from my assets folder?

Comment: sh_khan You may not believe me but I had written that exactly the same way, or maybe I had one thing off, but I swear I tried that and it didn't work, either way, its working now.  Thank you for your help